# CodeIgniter: How to remove index.php from url when using HTTPS and AWS

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, amazon-web-services

I am using HTTPS as the primary url and as per Google SEO guidelines I have to set the following redirects

1. http://example.com/      to https://example.com
2. http://www.example.com/  to https://example.com
3. https://www.example.com/ to https://example.com

The redirects which I have configured are working perfectly for homepage. However for the internal pages, only the first is working while 2nd and 3rd are adding index.php in the url.

**Example**

https://www.example.com/index.php/mobiles/apple/apple-iphone-se to https://example.com/index.php/mobiles/apple/apple-iphone-se

I am using the following code in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

#Block access for libwww-perl user-agent
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]


RewriteBase /

# Removes access to the system folder by users.
# Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
# previously this would not have been possible.
# 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]



RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^52\.34\.179\.108
RewriteRule (.*) https://priceoye.pk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

- Hosting: AWS (httpd)
- URL: PriceOye[dot]pk

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "first", "second" and "third"? Are you referring to the rules or the URLs listed at the beginning of the post?
Also, check the value of $config['index_page'] in config.php and set it to '' (empty string).

Comment: urls listed in the beginning of the post. $config['index_page'] is properly configured due to which urls set 1 mentioned in the question is working

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following two lines above ***RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.+)$ [NC]*** resolved the issue

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

create a file in your project folder named " .htaccess "
then type this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

then go to application > config > config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project_name/';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

make it like this